# How can I rotate 2D radar positions in Lua based on display rotation?

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I am attempting to create a radar system, it already displays positions of detected objects on a display but I need to be able to rotate those positions around the center by the rotation of the display.

I have researched this problem but any details I could find online didn't function properly and caused more problems.

```
...
for i, ship in ipairs(scan) do
        local xOffset = currentPos['x'] - ship['position']['x']
        local zOffset = currentPos['z'] - ship['position']['z']
        --Rotate xOffset and zOffset around center (0,0)
        
        local drawX = xMiddle + xOffset
        local drawZ = zMiddle + zOffset
        paintutils.drawPixel(drawX, drawZ, colors.blue)
        local textLen = string.len(ship['mass'])
        local textStart = drawX - textLen/2
        term.setCursorPos(textStart, drawZ-1)
        term.write(ship['mass'])
    end
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to rotate 2d cartesian coordinates `x`, `y` around the origin by an angle `delta` is to convert them to polar coordinates, then apply the rotation, then convert them back to cartesian coordinates. In code this looks as follows:

```lua
-- Rotates (x, y) around origin by the angle delta (in radians, counterclockwise)
local function rotate(x, y, delta)
    -- Convert to polar coordinates
    local length, angle = math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2), math.atan2(y, x)
    -- Rotate by delta
    angle = angle + delta
    -- Convert back to cartesian coordinates
    return length * math.cos(angle), length * math.sin(angle)
end
```

Example usage:

```lua
> rotate(1, 0, math.pi/4)
0.70710678118655    0.70710678118655
```

This rotates the point (1, 0) by 45° (`pi/4` in radians) counterclockwise, correctly yielding (sqrt(2), sqrt(2)).

If you use Lua 5.3 or newer, you'll have to use `math.atan` (which accepts two arguments) instead of `math.atan2`.

If you prefer degrees, simply use `math.rad(deg)` to convert your degrees to radians.